Find closest point from array
I try make table using array for example table like this
int array[5][3] = { {A, 200, 400}, {B, 300, 600}, {C, 100, 200}, {D, 200, 100}, {E, 200, 400} };

so array output will be like this :
| id |  X  |  Y  |
| A  | 200 | 400 | //First Row
| B  | 300 | 600 | //Second Row
| C  | 100 | 200 |
| D  | 300 | 100 |
| E  | 200 | 400 |

at this case example i have value :
int valueid = null; int valueX = 150; int valueY = 170;

so at this Case Nearest Point from table is ID C from table to my value.
my question is how to find nearest closet point from array table
I know only find sqrt for single row :
int cx = array[0][1] - valueX;
int cy = array[0][2] - valueY;
int FindClosest = sqrt(cx * cx + cy * cy);

how to count closest point from array table at code above only calculate closet point from First Row how to calculate from all row and print the result?

Write a loop to go through all the rows of your tables. Use a variable to keep track of the closest found so far. Update that variable if necessary on each iteration of the loop. When the loop is finished the variable will contain the closest distance. This is fairly basic stuff and would be explained in any beginner book on programming. If you want to learn to program you should buy a good book.

Without knowing your exact assignment or exercise (which you really should tell us) I would argue that A, B, etc. are just labels and should not be in the arrays. Besides that, please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. Then [edit] your question to improve it.

@john No raw loops ;)  (Sean Parent).

I would say that your question is "too beginnery". The obvious initial approach is to just iterate over the elements, and how to do it is explained at the beginning of any decent C++ book (BTW, we have a list of them ). Even though Pepijn Kramer already gave you a very good answer, without C++ basics you will not understand it.

@Someprogrammerdude sir easy understand its  how to print near value from my x y save int compare from  x y every row

The standard library has an algorithm section with all kinds of functions for commonly used algorithms that are tested and reusable. For your problem that would be std::min_element. To make min_element work in a readable way is model your points as Point (class/struct), not some multidimensional integer array (in which indices are used to represent x and y and an id).
After you've modeled a Point, you can make an array (or vector) of those.
The next step is to get std::min_element working by providing a compare function : which usually is provided in terms of a lambda expression.
Demo :https://onlinegdb.com/itNV7M3nG
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// Do NOT use `int array[5][3]` thats a semantically meaningless thing
// only showing HOW you are implementing things, but missing the point
// of describing what you are doing. That will make code hard to read

// So lets introduce a struct to represent a point in your array
// and a function to calculate distance between two of your points

struct Point
{
    std::string name;
    int x;
    int y;

    double distance(const Point& other) const
    {
        return std::sqrt((x - other.x) * (x - other.x) + (y - other.y) * (y - other.y));
    }
};

// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt
// print Point to output stream
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& point)
{
    os << "`" << point.name << "(" << point.x << "," << point.y << ")`";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    // resizable array (std::vector)    
    std::vector<Point> points{ { "A", 0, 0 }, { "B", 2, 2 }, { "C", 5, 5 }, { "D", 9, 9 } };

    // The point you want to find the closest point to
    Point somePoint{ "X", 3, 3 };

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    auto it = std::min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), 
        // Lambda expression : Capture `somePoint` by reference and then make a compare function that compares distance to `somePoint`for two points in the input
        [&](const Point& a,const Point& b) 
        { 
            return a.distance(somePoint) < b.distance(somePoint); 
        });

    // it is now an iterator referencing the closest point to `somePoint`
    std::cout << "Closest point to " << somePoint << " is " << *it << "\n";
}

Disclaimer, this is bit of a brute force approach. It will recalculate  distances (it could have seen before), I focused more on showing C++ style coding.

std::sqrt() is slow and is unnecessary.

@3CxEZiVlQ you are right It is to find the minimum (A SquaredDistance method should be added to Point and used in comarisson). But as said it is a bit of a brute force approach ;)

this is good but i have question how if A, B, C, D is int example  1 ,2 ,3, 4
so i want result int i = near point value;
example at your code is C is nearest but how if C is int number
and i want to fill i = near(C);
or maybe its can be int i = std::min_element(point.begin());
if i want to take value

Just replace the std::string name with a int index;  And then you can use int index = *std::min_element... to directly dereference the returned iterator.

@PepijnKramer no need for a separate index, just use it - points.begin()

@PepijnKramer i try being like this an got an error int i = min_element(points.begin());
could you give me sample code i'm sorry im new using c++

ah ok i'm understand sorry im noob

Don't talk yourself down like that, you're someone who wants to learn :)
All feedback from above in code : https://onlinegdb.com/dP4ywofao

not like thats example we found near is { 2, 4, 3} my quesion is how if i want take number 2
i = 2;
